# Intel DG965WH Motherboard

Tags: motherboard

what power supply do i need to get for this board. I believe I bought the wrong item. I got Ultra 600w X-Finity Power Supply w/2 80mm but I notice the fan is not spinning in the power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Fan is not spinning on the power supply? It could be DOA. Or you may have not set it up correctly. Do the motherboard fans/lights start up?

[Power Information for the DG965WH MB](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-012037.htm)

To know what your motherboard needs (power wise) you should read your motherboard manual. (Link below)

Important links:

- [DG965WH page from Intel website](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/DG965WH/index.htm)
- [Tested Power Supply List](http://www.intel.com/cd/channel/reseller/asmo-na/eng/tech_reference/box_desktop/int_inst_info/dsk_tested_source_lists/35829.htm)
- [DG965WH manual](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dg965wh/sb/CS-022978.htm)

600w should be enough to run your MB but also take consideration into what other components require power too.

Answer (score 0):

The fan inside the power supply is usually not controlled by the motherboard. As long as the motherboard make the powersupply 'on' then the fan should spin. Sound like it is broken